# remove requirement to include address in mass mail?

Tags: wordpress

Every time I try to send a mass mail the GUI tells me I need to include "{domain.address}", and I don't want to have that info in mass emails I send. How do I disable this requirement?

Alternatively, how do I remove my country from "Organization Address and Contact Info"? I removed state, zip code etc successfully but when I remove the country, save, and then go back and look at the page it just resets it to say "united states".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Administer/CiviMail/CiviMail Component Settings there's a checkbox for 'Disable check for mandatory tokens' - this is what you should tick to disable the check.